# Adjectives that do not have predicative position

Tags: grammar, adjectives, linguistics

I've read somewhere that some adjectives cannot be used in the predicative position; for example "this is a major problem" is acceptable, but "the problem is major" is not acceptable.

I'm wondering what other adjectives cannot be used in predicative position other than *major*. Is it the only one we have in English?

Comment: "The problem is major" sounds ok to me.

Comment: _Major_ can be used as predicative: "The use of drugs is a major problem."

Comment: @simchona, i see, so this page is wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Adjectives

Comment: I would suspect *major* is in transition.  I've heard people use it to mean *big* or *important* in very unprescribed ways.  I find it less likely that you'd say the *the candidate is presidential* to mean that they are a *presidential candidate*.

Comment: @kiamlaluna - That is not a predicative use, as *major* is still attributing *problem*.  The whole noun phrase *a major problem* is serving as a predicate, but that is irrelevant to the adjective's function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many kinds of non-predicative adjectives. A few examples:

- *former* president
- *electrical* engineer
- *alleged* criminal
- *main* reason

http://eecoppock.info/CoppockSemFest09.pdf shows you many *kinds* of examples. It is a good reference even if you choose to not read the technical bits.

Comment: The document highlights one of the most important ideas to the current theory on the matter: an adjective cannot serve as a predicate if it does not represent the conceptual "intersection" of it and the subject.  For example, *an electrical engineer* implies it is an *engineer*, but **does not** imply it is *electrical*.  (cf. *the vicious dog* is both *dog* and *vicious*)  The rule isn't all there is to say on the matter though, and there are oddities, like thematic adjectives. *The Spanish translator* could mean *the translator is Spanish*, but normally he/she simply translates Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

It is claimed that many adjectives cannot be used in a predicative position. Commonly, *entire*, *utter*, *former*, and *potential* are claimed to be of this type. Attributively, they look like this:

- The entire class helped.
- There was utter devastation.
- He's a potential client.
- He's a former client.

Personally, I have no problem using most these words in the predicative position. I'm a native English speaker, and they all seem fine to me. However, many English speakers have problems with:

- I toured the areas affected by the hurricane. The devastation was utter.
- He's so unlikely to spend any money, of all our possible future clients, I consider him the most potential.

To me at least, "the problem was major" is perfectly fine. If you asked me how anyone could find a problem with it, it likely wouldn't even occur to me that *major* is claimed to not be usable predicatively. But even I can't find any way to use *entire* predicatively.

Comment: Mathematicians studying complex analysis would have no problem saying *"This function is entire,"* but that's a [specific technical meaning.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)

Comment: this article claiemd that part on *major* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Adjectives

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but along the lines of Peter Shor's 'entire function' example, there are people who insist on saying 'the space has the Hausdorff property' rather than that 'the space is Hausdorff' should saying 'Hausdorff space' not suffice. I think the majority are happy with 'is Hausdorff', though.

Comment: I've never heard anybody say "this function has the entire property," and in fact that sounds to me as if it means something quite different.

Comment: I have seen some sources go over the top with things like *the space has the Hausdorff property* but I generally thought it was because they thought *the space is Hausdorff* was too simple and lacked the gravity of a good proof.  I couldn't think of any math terms that wouldn't fly in predicate, except for relative adjectives.  Like I would never say *the topology is discrete* or *the base is local* (on the fence about *the cover is open*). This all reminds me of my old Abstract Algebra professor, who would have a rant whenever a student (all too often) said two groups were *homomorphic*.