# "My day was ‘usual’ " or "My day was ‘ordinary’ "?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives

Which one is correct to use in a sentence, "My day was *usual*" or "My day was *ordinary*"?

Comment: *Usual* and *ordinary* mean slightly different things which a dictionary will help with. We can help with the sentence structure.

Answer (score 2):

*My day was ordinary* is preferable. *Ordinary* is an adjective that can be used both *attributively* (before the noun: *an ordinary day*) and *predicatively* (as a subject complement: *my day was ordinary*).

*Usual*, on the other hand is an adjective that is not commonly used *predicatively* (*?My day was usual*). Two other *non-predicative* adjectives are: *main* and *mere*:

> That is the main idea. (**That idea is main.*)
>
> She is a mere child. (**The child is mere*.)

There are some good answers to another question about *non-predicative adjectives* here: 
[Adjectives that do not have predicative position](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39655/adjectives-that-do-not-have-predicative-position)

Comment: Beat me to it! Have an upvote.

Comment: @Andrew. Sorry, It's irritating to work on an answer only to be beaten to the posting by a few seconds. And your point about the semantic difference between the two sentences is well-taken.